# Why is the Associativity Isomorphism Natural in a Category Closed Under Finite Products?

Tags: category-theory

From *Categories for the Working Mathematician*:

[image]

**Question:** I am concerned only with the associativity isomorphism $\alpha$, and understand everything in this theorem except the very last claim, that $\alpha$ is natural in $a$, $b$, and $c$ (which the author doesn't justify). Why is $\alpha$ natural?

I'm assuming the functors involved are each from $C \times C \times C$ to $C$ with $F(a,b,c) \mapsto a \times (b \times c)$ and $G(a,b,c) \mapsto (a \times b) \times c$.

Comment: You can explicitly compute $\alpha=\alpha^{-1}_2\circ \alpha_1$ by showing using UMP of the product(s) that there are isos $a\times (b\times c)\overset{\alpha_1}{\rightarrow}a\times b\times c$ and $(a\times b)\times c\overset{\alpha_2}{\rightarrow}a\times b\times c$. Naturality will follow by chasing the appropriate square.

Comment: @ChilangoIncomprendido: Yes, I see how that could work; however, you would still have to show that $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$ are both natural in $a$, $b$, and $c$, and it's not clear to me how to do that :)

Comment: I sketched this in an answer. I actually did this a long time ago. It's painful, but routine.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sketch of the argument: you can explicitly compute $\alpha=\alpha^{-1}_2\circ \alpha_1$ by showing using UMP of the product(s) that there are isos  $a\times (b\times c)\overset{\alpha_1}{\rightarrow}a\times b\times c$ and $(a\times b)\times c\overset{\alpha_2}{\rightarrow}a\times b\times c.$ Naturality will follow by chasing the appropriate square.

For example, with $F=-\times (b\times c),\ G=(-\times b)\times c,$ and $f:a\to a',$  you need to check that the following square commutes:

$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
a\times(b\times c) @>{\alpha_a}>> (a\times b)\times c\\
@VVV @VVV \\
a'\times(b\times c) @>{\alpha_{a'}}>> (a'\times b)\times c
\end{CD}$

That is, that $\alpha_{a'}\circ Ff=Gf\circ \alpha_{a'}.$ Explicitly, we require $\alpha_{a'}\circ (f\times (b\times c))=((f\times b)\times c)\circ \alpha_{a}.$

This result follows by construction of $\alpha$ and the definition of $F$ and $G$ on arrows.

Similarly, you can check naturality in the other arguments by considering the appropriate functors and squares. Naturality in the three arguments then follows by the functoriality of the trifunctors $(-\times-)\times -$ and $-\times(-\times -).$

Comment: "This result follows by construction of $\alpha $ and the definition of $F$ and $G$ on arrows." -- this is the key part of your explanation that I don't understand. :)

Comment: Show that $\pi_{a'\times b}\circ \alpha_{a'}\circ Ff=\pi_{a'\times b}\circ  Gf\circ \alpha_{a}$ and $\pi_{c}\circ \alpha_{a'}\circ Ff=\pi_{c}\circ  Gf\circ \alpha_{a}$ by direct computation.

Comment: What are the $\pi$ morphisms?

Comment: They are the projections from the product to the individual factors. To help with your calculations, it might be a good idea to review 1). the definition of product by the universal mapping property. 2). the definition of functors of the form $-\times x$  and $x\times -$. Then you can calculate $\alpha$ as outlined above and using 1) and 2) again,  show that the squares of the type outlined above commute.